# Android tablet fixed scrolling direction

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I've noticed, that on Android tablets, if you start to drag vertically, you can only scroll vertically, when you start to drag horizontally, you can only scroll horizontally. It automatically fixes direction in which you can scroll during single drag. But when you start to drag at some angle (for example 45°), you can freely scroll in all directions.

Anybody has any idea how to avoid scrolling direction fixing? I tried to find a solution on google, but no luck.

**Using js plugins like panzoom are not a solution, as they dramatically decrease speed.**

Comment: This behaviour is by design.

Comment: @CarolMcKay Yes... I can imagine that, but is there a way to turn it off or to avoid it somehow by site design?